# Part of Homework Question on convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Hi for a homework assignment I have to show that the series $(n^a)/n!$ is convergent, any starters or pointers would be much appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Use the ratio test.
If
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right| < 1$$
Then you proved your statement.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\begin{align}\cfrac{\frac{(n+1)^a}{(n+1)!}}{\frac{n^a}{n!}} &= \frac{(n+1)^a}{n!\cdot(n+1)}\cdot\frac{n!}{n^a}\\ &= \frac1{n+1}\cdot\frac{(n+1)^a}{n^a}\\ &= \frac1{n+1}\cdot\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^a\\ &= \frac1{n+1}\cdot\left(1+\frac1n\right)^a.\end{align}$$ Since $\frac1{n+1}\to 0$ and $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^a\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$ (why?), then what can conclude that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\cfrac{\frac{(n+1)^a}{(n+1)!}}{\frac{n^a}{n!}}=0.$$ (Why?) If you know the ratio test, you're done. If not, note that this means there is some $N$ such that $$\cfrac{\frac{(n+1)^a}{(n+1)!}}{\frac{n^a}{n!}}<\frac12$$ whenever $n\ge N.$ From this, we can prove that there is some positive constant $C$ such that $$0<\frac{n^a}{n!}<\frac{C}{2^n}$$ for all positive integers $n.$ What can we then conclude?

Comment: Lovely thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** : Go to logarithms and use Stirling approximation for Log(n!). Have a look at

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: How would this help?

Comment: My suggestion was stupid and I apologize. Cameron Buie's answer is much more useful and simpler ! Cheers.